# Как выровнять цифры на изображении?

Tags: изображения, php, imagemagick

Есть вот такая картинка
http://joxi.ru/8_kOVIwyTJDBAsGHBOg

Нужно убрать шум с фото, сделать картинку черно-белой и выровнять цифры в одну строку.

В какую сторону копать?

С картинками раньше не работал.

Реализация php или java.

Comment: А можно посмотреть код, который генерирует картинку для проверки?

Comment: На php использовал, для нахождения объектов по шаблону, либу ImageMagick . Предварительно ручками вырезав все встречающиеся варианты. Алгоритм муторный и дорогой. Копайте гугл в сторону распознавания капчи.

Comment: Да с шумами и выравниванием более менее разобрался.  
Есть ли какие-то реализованные на php алгоритмы для сравнения обьектов по шаблону, чтобы учитывался процент совпадения (т.к. пиксели +- могут отличаться)?